# How do i use a function to calculate, and use a void function to display?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm relatively new to a lot of the concepts in c++. It is school work. Right now i'm using

```
if(smartPhones >= 6000)
    commission = (smartPhones - 6000) * .25;
else(commission = 0);
if(serviceContracts >= 3500)
    commission1 = (serviceContracts - 3500) * .10;
else(commission1 = 0);
if(accessories >= 2000)
    commission2 = (accessories - 2000) * .05;
else(commission2 = 0);
if(maintenance >= 500)
    commission3 = (maintenance - 500) * .07;
else(commission3 = 0);
```

to calculate commission of cell phone sales. If someone sells more than 6000 phones, they are commissioned 25% of every phone over 6000, more than 3500 service contracts they are commissioned 10% of every contract over 3500. If they don't reach these limits they don't recieve any commission for that category.

I need to continually call and use a single function to calculate the commission of all 4 criteria(Smart Phones, Service Contracts, Accessories, and Maintenance Contracts). How would I do this properly, and what do I need to include inside the function? Am I able to use If/Else statements inside of the function?

```
double calcComm(double sales, double base, double percent)
{

}
```

After calculating commission, I need to use a void function to call on and display an arranged amount of data in columns and rows. something along the lines of

```
void display()
{
    double ID, totalCommission, smartPhones, serviceContracts, accessories, maintenance, commission, commission1, commission2, commission3, base, total;
cout << "Commission Statement for Salesman #: "<< ID << endl;
cout << left << "Product and Sales Amount " << endl;
cout << left << "Smart Phones: " << smartPhones << endl;
cout << left << "Service Contracts: "<< serviceContracts << endl;
cout << left << "Accessories: " << accessories << endl;
cout << left << "Maintenance Contracts: " << maintenance << endl;

cout << left << "Commission for all Products" << endl;
cout << left << "Smart Phones: " << commission << endl;
cout << left << "Service Contracts: " << commission1 << endl;
cout << left << "Accessories: " << commission2 << endl;
cout << left << "Maintenance Contracts: " << commission3 << endl;

cout << left << "Total Commission " << totalCommission << endl;
cout << left <<"Base Pay " << base << endl;
cout << left << "Total Due " << total << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to have a Commissions class containing all the types of commission and get first block of code to create (an populate) a Commissions instance.

you can then pass your Commissions instance to your display method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can use if-else in a function. In fact, you can use most C++ keywords (some are restricted in other contexts like `class`, `template`...)
2. Contrary to John3136 I think maybe an enum would be sufficient and would also fit the framework prescribed. Either way, you need to pass that function an argument that allows it to differentiate between different types of sales because the commission is not the same and the base is not the same. Inside the function, you can then use that argument and use if-else.

Comment: I'm just unsure of how to differentiate between the types of sales. When I run it, it asks for an ID, then for base salary(base) then how many smart phones I sold. With that # I need to call the calcComm function and run through it using that specific #. Then it asks for Service Contracts, need to do the same. Also with Accessories and Maintenance Contracts. How do i differentiate between which # is smart phones, which is service contracts and so on

Comment: As I said you can use an enum. If you haven't seen this yet in your course, you can use an integer or a character and use a code of some sort to identify which is which. You will need to pass this as an argument to your calcComm function.